# Possible techniques for rendering stars in space with OpenGL?

Tags: opengl

I have a large amount of stars (particles), scattered scarcely in a vast amount of space. I need to visualize this space somehow, including navigation in it. Obviously, I can't just feed OpenGL with all the real-space coordinates of my particles, looks like I need to perform severe processing and come up with something easy to render, like a texture or a small amount of points with OpenGL-friendly coordinates. 
So, the question is, are there common techniques for solving this task, and if not - how would you do it?

Comment: How many stars are we talking, and how large is the space?

Comment: @zacaj: let's say up to 10 000 in space of 1 cubic light year (cube wih 10^15 meters long side, I want to preserve mertic coordinates or fraction/multiple thereof). Surely, only a small fraction of space will be visible most of the time. I hoped I could just draw all points and OpenGL will take care of proper visualization, but now I see that at the very least GL can't work with scene of this depth.

Comment: Was the speed fine (disregarding depth problems)? There are ways of getting infinite depth out of opengl involving drawing the scene in layers by depth and clearing the depth buffer after each. A lot of people have to use them when they make large scale space exploration games.

Comment: @zacaj: just did a quick and dirty testing, performance is great so far. I don't think I got your idea, though. My knowledge of OpenGL barely extends beyound drawing points, so please elaborate. Is there a name for this technique?

Comment: Simply enough - experimentally.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get around depth buffer accuracy limitations fairly easy.  You just need to sort all your stars into various distances.  I'm not sure if there's a name, I've just seen it described in a few places

Say your depth buffer/projection matrix can go to 10,000 before you have accuracy problems, but you have stars as far away as 27,000.  You categorize your stars by how far they are away.  Stars 0 to 10,000 away go in the first bin, 10,000 to 20,000 goes in the second bin, etc.  Then begin to draw them:

1. Clear color and depth buffers
2. Set your projection matrix with near=20,000 and far=30,000
3. Draw all the stars between 20,000 and 30,000
4. Clear **only** the depth buffer
5. Set your projection matrix with near=10,000 and far=20,000
6. Draw all the stars between 10,000 and 20,000
7. Clear **only** the depth buffer
8. Set your projection matrix with near=0 and far=10,000
9. Draw all the stars between 0 and 10,000

Since you know that all the stars in the 10-20 bin are in front of all the stars in the 20-30 bin, you can safely clear the depth buffer, allowing you to bypass the accuracy limits of the depth buffer  and draw things as far away as you want

Comment: Thanks! Now I got it. An off-topic, but related question: I've learnt that corners of my screen (in XY plane) strictly correspond to points with coordinates (-1.0, -1.0) to (1.0, 1.0). How can I set/change this? Does this mean I'm doing something wrong, like setting perspective wrong or something (I use gluperspective and gluLookAt, which should alter coordinates of the visible area, if I understand it correctly)?

Comment: How exactly are you determining what they correspond to?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a method of layered sky cubes, onto which you render the stars and objects. If things are relatively close you can use parallax scrolling methods on the "matroyshka" arrangement of cubes.